# Why am I getting a "relation does not exist" error for existing table with sqlalchemy Metadata?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code which throws the following error

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:....', convert_unicode=True)

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
table = sqlalchemy.Table('omni.all_order', metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column('o_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('order', sqlalchemy.String),

)

ins = table.insert().values(all_rows)
engine.execute(ins)
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation
>   "omni.all_order" does not exist

But the following two codes work fine

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:....', convert_unicode=True)

    result = engine.execute("SELECT * from omni.all_order ")
    rows = result.fetchall()
    print(rows)
```

--

```
 engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:....', convert_unicode=True)

    engine.execute("INSERT INTO omni.all_order (o_id) VALUES (1) ")
```

Creating another table first in the same schema (omni) throws the same error

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:....', convert_unicode=True)

    result = engine.execute("CREATE TABLE omni.all_order_s(o_id INT, order VARCHAR(80))")

    metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    table = sqlalchemy.Table('omni.all_order_s', metadata,
        sqlalchemy.Column('o_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
        sqlalchemy.Column('order', sqlalchemy.String),

    )

    ins = table.insert().values(all_rows)
    engine.execute(ins)
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation
>   "omni.all_order_s" does not exist

but creating it outside of the schema works fine

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:....', convert_unicode=True)

    result = engine.execute("CREATE TABLE all_order_s(o_id INT, order VARCHAR(80))")

        metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
        table = sqlalchemy.Table('all_order_s', metadata,
            sqlalchemy.Column('o_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
            sqlalchemy.Column('order', sqlalchemy.String),

        )

        ins = table.insert().values(all_rows)
        engine.execute(ins)
```

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the table's schema using the [`schema=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.schema) keyword argument instead of including it in the table's name:

```
table = sqlalchemy.Table('all_order', metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column('o_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('order', sqlalchemy.String),
    schema='omni',
)
```

Currently it is quoted as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found the solution in this link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192897/postgres-relation-does-not-exist-error.

When you create the table name from a variable, the name is passed with quotes, so the name is case sensitive and need the quotes when you called again.